# Crear Estructura DO WHILE y acumuladores con HTML y Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, while

“El náufrago satisfecho” ofrece hamburguesas sencillas (s) y dobles (d), las cuales tienen un costo de $20 y $25 respectivamente.

Me dejaron este problema para desarrollar un programa en JS y HTML que permita ingresar el tipo de hamburguesa y acumular el costo correspondiente y repetir este proceso hasta que se acumule una suma de costos de $100 ó más.

Al finalizar el proceso repetitivo se debe mostrar en la página web el mensaje: "Tu Cuenta es " y la suma de los costos acumulados.

Nos dejaron un ejemplo pero no logro como colocar que las letras (s y d) se asocien con los costos ($20 y $25)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HAMBURGUESERIA</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Buenas tardes"); 
    alert("Bienvenido a 'El náufrago satisfecho'");
    alert("En breve tomaremos su orden");
    alert("En nuestro menú contamos con hamburguesas sencillas (s) a $20 y dobles (d) a $25");  

    var META = 100;
    var CUENTA = 0;

    do {
      // Dentro las llaves están las instrucciones que se van a repetir.

      AHORRO = Number(prompt("¿Qué quiere ordenar hoy? Ingrese 's' para hamburguesas sencillas o 'd' para hamburguesas dobles"));
      document.write("Has ahorrado " + AHORRO + " soles" + "<br>");

      CUENTA = CUENTA + AHORRO;
      document.write("Tu cuenta es " + CUENTA + " soles" + "<br><br>");
    }while (!(CUENTA >= META));

    document.write("<h1> Has alcanzado la meta</h1>");
    document.write("<h1> Has AHORRADO " + CUENTA + " soles. </h1>")
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido Dian, el problema está en que no estas leyendo de ningún sitio las variables 's' o 'd', en Javascript puedes hacerlo con algún componente HTML por ejemplo: <input type="text" id="tipoHamburguesa"> y luego obtenerlo por Id usando el DOM del HTML https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El prompt pide que entres s o d, según sean sencillas o doble y también tienes que meter una cantidad. Hay dos caminos:

1. todo en un prompt: pondrías por ejemplo 10s para 10 sencillas o 20d para 20d dobles. El último carácter de da el tipo de hamburguesa si es "s" costo será 20y si es "d" será 25. El número lo sacas con un parseInt sobre el texto:

   ```
   var META = 100;
   var CUENTA = 0;
   var costo, tipo;
   do{
   AHORRO = prompt("¿Qué quiere ordenar hoy? Ingrese cantidad seguida de 's' para hamburguesas sencillas o 'd' para hamburguesas dobles");
   tipo = AHORRO.substr(-1);//obtiene la letra final
   switch (tipo){
       case 's':
           costo = 20;    
           break;
       case 'd':
           costo = 25;
           break;
       default:
           costo=0;
   }
   AHORRO = parseInt(AHORRO)*costo;  //obtiene el valor numérico del texto entrado
   document.write("Has ahorrado " + AHORRO + " soles" + "<br>");
   if(isNaN(CUENTA) CUENTA=0; //un seguro: evitar bucle infinito si hay datos malos
   CUENTA = CUENTA + AHORRO;
   document.write("Tu cuenta es " + CUENTA + " soles" + "<br><br>");
    }
   while (!(CUENTA >= META));
   document.write("<h1> Has alcanzado la meta</h1>");
   document.write("<h1> Has AHORRADO " + CUENTA + " soles. </h1>") ;
   ```
2. Usar dos prompt: uno para el tipo y otro para la cantidad. el único cambio respecto al método 1 es cambiar AHORRO = prompt(... y la siguiente por estas lineas

   ```
   tipo = prompt("¿Qué tipo de hamburguesa quiere? Ingrese 's' para hamburguesas sencillas o 'd' para hamburguesas dobles");
   AHORRO = Number(prompt("¿Cuántas quieres?"));
   ```

Se ve que es un ejercicio para iniciarse en Javascript y esta solución es muy mejorable pero creo que es la que necesitas ahora.
Y te comento:

1. aunque se pueda hacer, poner los nombres de las variables todo en Mayúsculas no queda muy bien,
2. Usa nombres de variables relacionados con su objetivo, por ejemplo AHORRO indica eso, cuanto te ahorras, y aquí se usa para calcular el precio total, podrías llamarla precioPedido por ejemplo.
3. Muy bien por declarar las variables con var
4. Muy bien por los ; al final de cada sentencia
5. Muy bien por el comentario en el código.

Para una cosa rápida como ésta el document.write vale, pero recuerda que esta forma de escribir en la página está desaconsejada.

Sigue adelante que vas bien

Comment: No estás considerando los posibles errores, por ejemplo, cuando el usuario cancela el `prompt` o deja el campo vacío, `AHORRO` va a ser `null` o cadena vacía y `AHORRO.substr(-1)` va a fallar. Por otra parte, está bien declarar las variables con `var`, pero sería mejor con [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), a menos que se desee compatibilidad con navegadores antiguos. De cualquier forma, buena respuesta.

Comment: Evidentemente hay muchas cosas sin atar en este ejemplo como comento en la solución, pero me parece que es un ejemplo muy básico para complicarlo. Lo más sofisticado ha sido el seguro de bucle infinito porque lo he visto imprescindible.  Me parece que es un ejemplo para practicar bucles y condicionales.

Comment: No estoy criticando tu respuesta, porque me parece muy bien apuntar las buenas prácticas y por eso el voto positivo. Solo hice el comentario porque creo que encaminar correctamente no es sinónimo de complicar, al contrario, tener en cuenta los posibles errores al inicio del aprendizaje, le ahorrará a OP muchos dolores de cabeza (y tiempo) en el futuro.

Comment: Necesito emoticones!!!! :) No, hombre, no veo nada mal el comentario. está perfecto y es de agradecer. La puntualización es más bien para el autor de la pregunta. Estoy contigo en los apuntar que los códigos siempre hay que pulirlos y ser conscientes de los posibles errores.  Tu aportación es estupenda en este sentido.

Comment: muchas gracias!